# Splitting each element of an array into an another array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm currently working on a C++ project. For this project, I need to split elements of an array into another array. I will specify my need. Currently, I have an array like this:

```
array_1 = [first,second,third]
```

I need to change this array to something like this:

```
array_2 = [[f,i,r,s,t],[s,e,c,o,n,d],[t,h,i,r,d]]
```

How can I do this? it would be a great help for me. Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: I don't think the pseudocode you wrote makes clear what your issue is. Could you edit your question to rewrite it in C++? The types are unclear.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? How did you attempt work or not work? And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

C++ provides a plethora of solutions for this problem. A convenient way is to use `vector`. See the following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> array_1 = {"first","second","third"};
    vector< vector<char> > array_2;
    
    for(int i(0); i < array_1.size(); ++i){
        vector<char> charVec(array_1[i].begin(), array_1[i].end()); 
        array_2.push_back( charVec );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the std vector library for this. In this example I worked with strings and chars but should be the same way for others types (the std vector library works with templates).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    //We initialize our vectors
    std::vector<std::string> array1;
    array1.push_back("first");
    array1.push_back("second");
    array1.push_back("third");

    std::vector<char> array2;
    //Now, using the string's fuction .size() we can iterate our string and save
    //each character into array2 with push_back()
    for(int i=0; i<array1.size(); i++)
    {
        std::string aux = array1[i];
        for(int j=0; j<aux.size(); j++)
        {
            array2.push_back(aux[j]);
        }
    }
    //Finally we print the result
    for(int i=0; i<array1.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",array1[i].c_str());
    }
    for(int i=0; i<array2.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n",array2[i]);
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have types in your `array_1` so I am assuming it is `std::vector<std::string>`

```
std::vector<std::string> array_1 = {"first", "second", "third"};
```

and assuming array_2 is a vector of char vectors: `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`

you need to loop over `array_1` then loop over each character in each string. create a new vector and put it into `array_2`

```
for(const auto& word : array_1)
{
    std::vector<char> vec;
    for(const auto& c : word)
    {
        vec.push_back(c);
    }
    array_2.push_back(vec);
}
```

full working implementation would be:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> array_1 = {"first", "second", "third"};
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> array_2 = {};
    for(const auto& word : array_1)
    {
        std::vector<char> vec;
        for(const auto& c : word)
        {
            vec.push_back(c);
        }
        array_2.push_back(vec);
    }
}
```